# scala coding-style: initialize a val Seq depending on optional values

Tags: scala, collections, coding-style

I'm developing a simple function that should build a sql condition based on optional parameters that might not be present.

I'm trying to accomplish it using immutables values, and in and elegant and idiomatic way.

So far now I came with something like this:

```
val cond: Seq[String] = Nil ++ 
  (if (entity != "*") Seq("entity = {entity}") else Nil) ++
  (if (name != "*") Seq("name = {name}") else Nil) ++

val condition = 
  if (cond.size == 0) "" 
  else " where " + cond.mkString(" and ") + " "
```

So, I'm just mergins Seqs, if the value is not present I'm merging it with Nil

Working with a var I get something like:

```
var cond: Seq[String] = Seq();
if (entity != "*") cond = cond :+ "entity = {entity}"
if (name != "*") cond = cond :+ "name = {name}"
```

Which I find it to be more readable (I wonder if this second approach is not threadsafe because of the var)

I wanted to know what would be a scala idiomatic and elegant way to solve such a thing

-- edit

in the end, I settled down with this implementation:

```
val condition: String = {

  var cond: Seq[String] = Seq();

  if (entity != "") 
    cond = cond :+ "entity = {entity}"
  if (filter != "")
    cond = cond :+ """(name like {filter} or prev like {filter} or post like {filter})"""

  if (cond.size == 0) "" 
  else " where " + cond.mkString(" and ") + " "
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is to keep the mutable construction, but hidden in a block to avoid side effects:

```
val cond = {
  var cs = Seq[String]()
  if (entity != "*") cs = cs :+ "entity = {entity}"
  if (name != "*") cs = cs :+ "name = {name}"
  cs
}
```

Such construct is perfectly safe because the `var` is not accessible outside the block. You could also use a val with a mutable builder, for instance a`ListBuffer`. In that case. Just be sure you don't leak a mutable object out of the block:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val cond = {
  val cs = ListBuffer[String]()
  if (entity != "*") cs += "entity = {entity}"
  if (name != "*") cs += "name = {name}"
  cs.result() //Converts the ListBuffer into an immutable List
}
```

This is perfectly acceptable because the block itself is still "pure". This pattern appears in the Scala API.

Comment: at last, var appears! ;-) a few months into Scala and have been struggling to find an acceptable use case for var

Comment: great answer!!! and excellent tip! could you provide a lin the the Scala API section in which it appears?

Comment: Check this file for `ListBuffer` occurences: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala

Comment: @virtualeyes Var are also useful in Akka, where the Actor state must be mutable.

Answer (score 5):

Don't repeat yourself:

```
def seqIf(r: String, s: String) = if (r != "*") Seq("%s = {%s}".format(s,s)) else Nil

val cond = seqIf(entity, "entity") ++ seqIf(name, "name")
```

Not only strings:

```
def seqIf[A](p: Boolean, a: A) = if (p) Seq(a) else Nil

val cond = seqIf(entity != "*", "entity = {entity}") ++ 
  seqIf(name != "*", "name = {name}")
```

Comment: great tip, BTW, why do you define the second parameter in a separarte parameter group, so as to curry the function? and why do you declare the type [A]?

Comment: @opensas - Sorry, was typing quickly and was going to make it more generic.  I'll simplify.

Comment: @Rex - If there is no instance of `seqIf` with another test, why don't  you define it this way: `def seqIf(v: String, s: String) = if (v != "*") Seq("%s = {%s}".format(s,s)) else Nil`?

Comment: @Nicolas - If that really is the only test, I agree.

Comment: @Rex, hey I'd like to see the more generic version, I still can't get the hold of currying ;-)